# Format Date to show "Today"/"Tomorrow" instead of Month-Day in JqxGrid

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, jqxgrid

We're using jqxgrid to show room informations on a screen. For the sake of readability we try to format the date to "today" or "tomorrow" instead of the actual date (of today or tomorrow...).

Everything works (grid is showing everything it should) except the reformatting to "today" and "tomorrow". We tried using moment.js, but somehow it won't work.

This is our **source**:

```
 datatype: "json",
        datafields: [
            {name: 'title', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'room_name', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'room_number', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'start', type: 'date', format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"},
            {name: 'end', type: 'date', format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"},
            {name: 'email', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'comment', type: 'string'}

            ...

  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
        columns: [
                {text: 'Raum #', dataField: 'room_number', width: 120},
                {text: 'Raum-Name', dataField: 'room_name', width: 340},
                {text: 'Von', dataField: 'start', width: 190, cellsalign: 'center', cellclassname: "startdate"},
                {text: 'Bis', dataField: 'end', width: 190, cellsalign: 'center', cellsformat: 'dd.MM'},
                ....
```

**Note**: Output in the gridcell "VON" looks like this: **Thu Aug 28 2014 16:30:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)**

As you can see, the *start date* is wrapped in the div-class `startdate`.

We tried it via a javascript to reformat it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function formatDate(date) {
        date.each(function(){
            var formattedDate = $(this).text();
            var d = moment(formattedDate);
            $(this).html( d.format("dddd, MMMM Do"));

        });
};

formatDate($('.startdate'));
});
```

This works perfectly when we use it on a div that's **outside** the jqxgrid. It does not, however, work inside it. Any ideas?

**Update**: This does the trick:

```
 window.setTimeout(function(){
            console.log($('.startdate div').innerHTML);
            formatDate($('.startdate div'));
        }, 2000);
```

The divs are generated later, as gp correctly stated. Anyway, might there be a better solution?

Comment: probably when you call formatDate, the divs are not yet generated so $('.startdate') will not select those divs yet. did you check that?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it, you're right. 
`window.setTimeout(function(){
            console.log($('.startdate div').innerHTML);
            formatDate($('.startdate div'));
        }, 2000);`
 does the trick. But ain't there a better solution?

Comment: try calling formatDate after $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid() method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add your formatting call to the grid's ready function:

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
    {
        columns: [ ... ],
        ready: function() {
            formatDate($('.startdate'));   
        },
        ....
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the divs (.startdate) are generated in the grid before you call formatDate.

Best would be to use the "initialized" event of the jqxgrid.

```
$('#jqxgrid').on('initialized', function () {
    formatDate($('.startdate div'));
});
```